# removeEventListener not working on Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I have a listener set on the root of my Firebase Database -

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
rootDB = database.getReference();
```

I have a listener set up as follows -

```
groupListener = (new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

Log.i("ValueEventListener", "Count :" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
.... more code...
```

I attach the listener as below -

```
rootDB.addValueEventListener(groupListener);
```

Then as I load a new activity, I want this to stop listening so I use -

```
rootDB.removeEventListener(groupListener);
```

It seems to keep listening, can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

I know I can use a single event listener but I want it to keep monitoring while it's in this activity but not when in other activities.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you adding the removeEventListener? You should preferably do it in the onDestroy of the First activity

Comment: It's in a method that calls the new Activity.  I want it to stop as it loads the new Activity, onDestroy doesn't get called then.  So what I've done, I moved it to onDestroy, but I finish() the first activity as I call the second, and it STILL uses the ValueEventListener...

Comment: @AndyCr15 Hey, I am facing the exact same issue. So how did you resolved this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember now 

Answer (score 7):

three suggestions:

**1.** You may be adding listener more than once.

> If a listener has been added multiple times to a data location, it is
>   called multiple times for each event, and you must detach it the same
>   number of times to remove it completely.
>    ([from here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write))

**2.** The listener you are adding may not be *the same one* you are removing.
Here CASE 1 will remove the listener while CASE 2 will not:

```
//CASE 1:
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {....}
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(listener);
databaseRef.removeEventListener(listener);

//CASE 2:
public ValueEventListener listener(){
    return new ValueEventListener() {....}
}
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(listener());
databaseRef.removeEventListener(listener());
```

**3.** As a workaround, you can set a boolean and change it's value when you want to stop/start listening:

```
groupListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(isListening){
            //...
        }
    }
```

Hope one of them helps..

Answer (score 4):

This is maddening!

From what I can tell, the `removeEventListener` method is asynchronous and will *eventually* be removed.  But if you are trying to quickly switch from one `DatabaseReference` to another (such as a `$uid` path), then you're going to have the duplicate calls. I'm not found a synchronous way to resolve this.

After hours of debugging and much of my live stolen from me, I extended the `ChildEventListener` interface, add the `isListening` functionality that @Ahmed mentions above.  Now I see that while initially there are duplicate calls to `onChildAdded`, they do eventually subside.

GLWY!!